# Repositioning fancybox to center after loading new ajax content

Tags: fancybox

I have implemented a fancybox which opens and loads ajax content without any problems. But when I load new ajax content into a div in the FancyBox using jquery I need to center the FancyBox on the screen again.

```
function refreshContent(url) {
    $("#content").fadeOut("slow", function(){
      $.fancybox.showLoading();
      $("#content").load(url,false, function() {         
        $.fancybox.hideLoading()
        $("#content").fadeIn("slow");
        $.fancybox.reposition();
    });
  })
```

As you can see, I have tried with the reposition() method, but with no effect. The same applies to center()

What am I missing here?

I'm using Fancybox ver 2.0.5

Answer (score 6):

Maybe is a little late but in fancy 2 there is a method:

$.fancybox.reposition();

You can see the other methods here:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Probably need to put you reposition call inside the complete function of the fadeIn. Otherwise it gets called before the content is visible.

Comment: You sir, just saved my day! Been struggling for about an hour now not understanding why it just wouldn't reposition. Without this answer I would have missed the fact that the call was outside the onComplete function of animate :-)